# Where is zsh storing my history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I have two terminals open, both running zsh.
The history options which I currently have set are these:

```
export HISTFILE=~/.histfile
export HISTSIZE=10000
export SAVEHIST=10000
setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
setopt HIST_EXPIRE_DUPS_FIRST
setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS
setopt APPEND_HISTORY
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

When I type `history`, or `fc -l`, in either terminal, I see the last 16 commands (numbered). These histories are different in either shell, and are both different from what I see when I look inside `.histfile`.

As far as I can tell from the `man zshoptions` page, this is to be expected, and upon exiting the shell, its commands will be appended to the history.

In that case, where is each terminal's individual history stored until that point?

Comment: In memory, like all other shells.

Comment: and drops it to history file only on logout / exit.

Comment: Thanks - judging by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243983/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-the-history-in-zsh there is no other way to edit that history other than to logout/exit, then edit the newly saved lines in `.histfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` option, if set, causes a more immediate write of history entries. Also note `SHARE_HISTORY`, which if set may cause new shells to pick up on something it sounds like you want to remove from history. Rewriting the history live depends on these options, as if you do not care about other commands in that particular instance of the shell, and `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` is not set, simply clobber the history of that shell with `fc -R`:

```
% echo super secret password
super secret password
% echo whoopsie 
whoopsie
% history -2
18030  echo super secret password
18031  echo whoopsie
% fc -R $HISTFILE
% history -3
36060  vim ~/.zshrc
36061  man readpassphrase
36062  mutt
%
```

And then confirm with `$EDITOR $HISTFILE` that that super secret password isn't in the history file (also! note that there may be a `zshaddhistory` function (or array of functions), in which case you'll need to inspect what that function (or those functions) does (do)). With `INC_APPEND_HISTORY`, the entry is probably in `$HISTFILE`, so editing the history file to remove the bad entry and then `fc -R $HISTFILE` should clear it from both the history file and the shell. With `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY` and if you suspect new shells have picked up that bad history entry, you'll need to do `fc -R` in all of those shells, or close them all, check that none have written the bad line back out to the history file, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this is becoming clearer.  Before I had read anything, I had assumed , completely incorrectly, that the history file operated in the manner of `SHARE_HISTORY`.  Can you point me to any documentation for `fc -R`? I can't find anything inside `man fc`. When I see the word 'clobber' I know I'd better read the docs first!

Comment: `man zshall | less -p '^[ ]*fc '` and then hit `n` a few times. (Or `bindkey | grep run-help` though I don't use that.)

Comment: on OS X run-help opens the `builtins` man page instead of `zshall`